# HTML or CSS Change text from object data

Tags: html, css

I'm importing a text from a php file into my HTML, the problem is that i want the text to have a gray color and it's imported as black. I've tried to change it from CSS but it's not working. Does anybody have any idea how can i solve this issue?

Thanks

```
<div class="box" style="width:100%">
        <h2>Change Log</h2>
        blablalblalbla
        <p>
            <object data="http://www.mysite.com/changelogordered.php" type="text/html" width="100%">
                <p>[Cannot load http://www.mysite.com/changelogordered.php]</p>
            </object>
        </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason to do this with an object?
Why not use an iframe or a regular ajax call from JavaScript?

Comment: So if I get this correctly ... you want to display text you got from your server, or display a message if the request failed?

Comment: Well, the code listed can do that without any issue....what i want is the displayed text from the server to have a gray color, not black...
http://jsfiddle.net/cCvNf/2/

Comment: It is possible that other css classes affect your text. so try this, give a class to text say `testClass`, then you can try this `.testClass{color: gray !important;}`

Comment: it will work only for the header and text, it will not work for the imported text from the php file.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a regular Ajax call (hint use jQuery!: [ajax api referene](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))
The main reason why I suggest this, is that you keep dealing with regular HTML, which is easy to style, rather than objects.

An example from the top of my head:

```
<style>
    #reply-from-server{
        overflow:scroll;
        height:300px;
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<div class="box" style="width:100%">
    <h2>Change Log</h2>
    blablalblalbla
    <div id="reply-from-server"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/changelog1.php",
    success: displayText,
    error: showError
});
function displayText(data){
    $("#reply-from-server").append(data);
}
function showError(data){
   var mess = "An error occured!";
   $("#reply-from-server").text(mess);
}
```

**NOTE** This is posted in the jQuery website:
Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Javascript with latest jQuery:

```
$.ajax("/changelog1.php").done(displayText).fail(showError);

function displayText(data){
    $("#reply-from-server").append(data);
}
function showError(data){
   var mess = "An error occured!";
   $("#reply-from-server").text(mess);
}
```

Comment: seems it doesn't work.....just tried it....changed the url to www.predeal-trophy.ro/changelog1.php it's not displayed.

Comment: I also added a link to the official documentation :)

Comment: An error occured! .....doesn't read the text from php ....the file it's on the server as i mentioned....

Comment: uhm .. the file is on the same domain as your website I trust? or else this won't work ...

Comment: yes it it.....i've done a test also....if i will input only the filename(*.php without any url pattern) it will display the text....but it will display also the code.....<ul><li>
 <li>Added feature to copy a layout ( from Tree Pane ) into another layout. 
 <li>On small zoom move column or create fk is not allowed. Instead is done drag table.
 <li>Linux default look and feel to MetalLookAndFeel.
 <li>Fix for Firebird ALTER TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: could you post the error ? (use F12 in chrome and have a look in the console)

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.predeal-trophy.ro/changelog1.php. Origin http://predeal-trophy.ro is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: that means your current website is not hosted on the same domain as your text file. 
Are you testing from a local server?

Comment: i've uploaded the files on the server and tested directly in the browser....both files are on the same server.

Comment: could you post the link to your website? The exact page where the page should be displayed?

Comment: i've modified the url....but seems it's not working...have a look here: http://predeal-trophy.ro/testurl/download.html

....now the error it's different: http://predeal-trophy.ro/testurl/predeal-trophy.ro/changelog.1php 404 (Not Found) .....the actual url of the file is located on: predeal-trophy.ro/changelog1.php

Comment: Ok....i've moved the php file in the same folder.....and modified the url...now it's working...but it's displaying also the tags.... <ul><li>....how can i make it displayed without the tags....

Comment: I updated my solution to your specific needs.
I tested it directly on your website from the chrome developer tools and it worked for me. DO MIND that I changed the 'p' tag to a 'div' tag!

Comment: No problem. This is just one solution by the way. I suggested JavaScript because you tagged your question with HTML5 and CSS3, since you are using PHP, you could include the file directly. However, my php days are a few years behind and I have no idea how to do that. However I suggest you have a look at it.

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html

Comment: thanks...one more question :) how can i create a scrollbar so if the text is longer it won't be displayed on the whole page?

Comment: Note that `success` and `error` have been deprecated in the latest version of jQuery. Use `done()` and `fail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add style to object

```
object{
    color:red       
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cCvNf/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, but it doesn't work.....the imported text it's still black.....what it will change....it will color only the text if the page it`s not available.

Comment: @user2143407 could you post the rendered code when it is loaded with the external file and check if it is taking any tags in it

Comment: Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/cCvNf/2/

The code in PHP it's like this

<ul><li>
<li>Added feature to copy a layout ( from Tree Pane ) into another layout. 
<li>On small zoom move column or create fk is not allowed. Instead is done drag table.
<li>Linux default look and feel to MetalLookAndFeel.
<li>Fix for Firebird ALTER TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY.